# DropBox Delayed Upload

Tags: dropbox, instant-upload

How long does it normally take for Dropbox to upload photos that I take on my camera?
I took some photos on Saturday and then my phone suddenly stopped working on Sunday. I keep checking my Dropbox online and it still hasn't uploaded. I have a Galaxy S5.

Comment: Dropbox had some hacking issues lately, they may be having some issues / failed uploads. Perhaps reach out to Dropbox inc?

Comment: Reviewing this question, have you been able to answer this question? If my answer suffices please mark it so, if you have the solution please answer your own question of let us know if it is still not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough I just enabled it and tested, instant. Now I apologize for the 'answer', I cannot comment.

First we need to ensure that you're uploading is not set to WiFi only, and you're trying to upload via mobile data. That would be a painful issue.

Now if you have Auto-Sync on, it will usually run at the next set run. Possibly try clearing cache (within the app) and try again, it should spark Drop Box to recheck. If you're really enthusiastic, unlink your device, go to settings, clear data and re-login.

Once again, apologizes, I'd prefer to comment.

Answer (score 0):

> How long does it normally take for Dropbox to upload photos that I
>   take on my camera?

After using Dropbox for a while, I started using it on my Android phone, and Dropbox doesn't seem to be as clever at sync on that.

Unless/until they improve Dropbox, the answer to your question is rhetorical: "How long is a piece of string?".

However, I've found I can usually cause it to sync by turning the phone to flight mode briefly. On coming out of flight mode, I then see the new file updates in Dropbox.